# AttributeError qsbk instance has no attribute 'stories'

Tags: python, instance, attributeerror

my coding is as follows.

First is my class setting

```
class qsbk:
    # standalize some variables
    def __int__(self):
        self.stories = []
        self.pageIndex = 1
        self.user_agent = 'Mozilla/4.0(compatible;MS IE 5.5;Windows NT)'
        #standalize headers
        self.headers = {'User-Agent': self.user_agent}
        self.enable = False
```

Then activate loadpage

```
def loadpage(self):
    if self.enable == True:
        if len(self.stories) < 2:
```

The error is:

> File "C:/Python27/webcapture2.py", line 41, in loadpage
>       if len(self.stories) < 2:
>
> AttributeError: qsbk instance has no attribute 'stories'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor should be `__init__` but you named it as `__int__`

That might be the cause. Check it out

Comment: Thanks. If that helped you, please mark it as answered

Comment: I don't know how, I vote for you answer serveral times but it shows that I have less than 15 reputation.....which means my vote would not be recorded.